# Fetch JSON Response Into Propertylist For UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to store JSON response Into propertylist like below Image of plist structured.

My Response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": "1000",
        "girls": {},
        "boys": {
            "0": {
                "name": "sam"
            },
            "1": {

                "name": "jhon"
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "keen"
            },
            "3": {

                "name": "man"
            },
            "4": {

                "name": "blue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to Achieve :

[image: Something like this]

`FYI:` After stored all the Information's I need to get `Girls array` data and `Boys array` data based on `segment` button selection It should reload the data quickly on tableview.

Needed  Help :

How to fetch all the `JSON` data like my posted Image `plist` structure?
How to get and load It Into `UItableview NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First step:**

> Convert JSON string to dictionary

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [strJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:&jsonError];
```

**Second Step:**

> Make a dictionary for plist

```
NSMutableDictionary * tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tempDict setObject:[[json objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"girls"] forKey:@"girls"];
[tempDict setObject:[[json objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"boys"] forKey:@"boys"];
```

**Last Step:**

> Write this dictionary to pList file

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPlistFile.plist"];
[tempDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];
```

EDIT : If you dont want to write this dict to plist file, ignore last step.

Just use your tempDict as tableView dataSource.

Number of sections : `[[tempDict allKeys] count]`

Number of rows in section :

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    return [[tempDict objectForKey:@"girls"] allKeys];
}
else
{
    return [[tempDict objectForKey:@"boys"] allKeys];
}
```

for cell configuration,

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    lblTitle.text = [[[tempDict objectForKey:@"girls"] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
else
{
    lblTitle.text = [[[tempDict objectForKey:@"boys"] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Hope this will help you....

Comment: I want to store into plist first but by using ur great code little mistake into plist Its createing girls as a Dictionaries and boys too. I need to create that should array like posted Image@Nirav Gadhiya

Comment: I am using two segmant button one tableview. Whenever I calik the first segment button girls data will load on table same for segment two button boys will data load@Nirav Gandhiya

Comment: do you have only one key in dictionary? like - {"name": "sam"}

Comment: No totaly 5 keys but I put Sample there! Its comming from JSON!@Nirav Gandhiya

Comment: Gandhiya.How to load on tableview from dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

See the below worked out example

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"response": @{
                                     @"count": @"1000",
                                     @"girls": @{},
                                     @"boys": @{
                                             @"0": @{@"name": @"sam"},
                                             @"1": @{@"name": @"jhon"},
                                             @"2": @{@"name": @"keen"},
                                             @"3": @{@"name": @"man"}
                                             }
                                     }
                             };
//return boys count while loading boys.
return [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"boys"] allKeys].count;

//return girls count while loading boys.
return [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"girls"] allKeys].count;

//Use this in cell for indexpath for row.
NSDictionary *boys = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"response"] valueForKey:@"boys"];
NSString *nameString = [[boys valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]] valueForKey:@"name"];

//To get all name of boys at once
NSArray *boysName = [boys valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

Comment: @Sanju i added the cellForRowAtIndePath code too please check. it will help.

Comment: Its not loading into table buddy. Can u please post it with method?@Avinash Tag

Comment: @Sanju send me code zip I will check where is the mistake and let you know

Comment: I did buddy Thank you so much for your great help! Btw only one doubt while I am clicking cell need to take all the values. above mentioned code only one particular values we are taking @Avinash Tag

Comment: @sanju please check the last line I append the code.

Comment: Buddy wait! I need to store girls sepearate NSMUtableArray and boys seprate NSMUtableArray!@Avinash Tag!