# How To Create Segment Control Button Click To Reload TableData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create `Plist dictionary` data's read and load into tableview. Here, I am maintaining two `segment` control button and single `tableview`. Whenever I selected segment control button one I need to load first plist dictionary data then button two to load second one. I need to differentiate two `data` set and based on button click It should reload.

My Code:

```
    // to read data
    NSArray *pathse = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = pathse.firstObject;
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"port.plist"];
    savedUrl = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];

- (IBAction)Click_Segmentbutton:(id)sender {

    switch (segment_Button.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:{

           break;}
        case 1:{

           break;}
    }
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"boysinfo"] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"girlsinfo"] count];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Here I need to get whenever click the tableview cell selected cell all details

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to your question, below is code for your purpose.

```
//Global
NSMutableDictionary *savedPlistDictionary;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

   //Read the plist and save in plistDictionary.

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsPathString = paths.firstObject;

   NSString *plistNameString = @"second.plist";  //Second plist file
   NSString *plistPathString = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistNameString];
   plistDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: plistPathString];
```

}
    //Function to fetch the plist file based on index (segment selected)
    - (void)saveDataWithSelectedIndex:(int)index {

```
   if (index == 1){

      savedPlistDictionary = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"boysinfo"];

   }
   else {

      savedPlistDictionary = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"girlsinfo"];

   }

}

- (IBAction)Click_Segmentbutton:(id)sender {

   //Pass the selected index segment to function and savedPlistDictionary will be updated accordingly

    switch (segment_Button.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:{
         [self saveDataWithSelectedIndex:0];  
           break;}
        case 1:{
         [self saveDataWithSelectedIndex:1];
           break;}
    }

  [self.tableView reloadData]; //Reload the tableView

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

   return [savedPlistDictionary count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Here parse the data and load cells

}
```

Comment: Btw Its not two plist Its only one plist two Dictionary. please referer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542488/fetch-json-response-into-propertylist-for-uitableview/34542601?noredirect=1#comment56830080_34542601

Comment: Index? Its missed variable. Its confusing! - (void)readPlistWithIndex:(int)index  but I am reading plist into view didload
 @nikhil84

Comment: Please for future question do format your code/question properly for reader's understanding. Also now check the code I have updated it.